# ProgressDialog not displaying

Tags: android, progressdialog

I have a progress dialog, I want it to show and dismiss when my method has finished executing. now, I have this:

```
progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
                progressDialog.setMessage("Downloading...");
                progressDialog.show();
                new Thread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        try{
                            DownloadMethod(s);
                            progressDialog.dismiss();
                        }catch (Exception e){
                            Toast.makeText(prefs.this, "We can't reach the data...Try again", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }

                    }
                }).start();
```

My method `DownloadMethod` is executed but never shows the dialog.

Comment: What is DownloadMethod?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, It must be throwing an exception with `progressDialog.dismiss();` call because you cannot update UI from a worker thread, instead use [`AsyncTask`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

e.g pass parameter to constructor

```
 private class DownloadFilesTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    TypeOf_S s;

     public DownloadFilesTask(TypeOf_S s){
        this.s = s;
     }

     @Override
     protected Void doInBackground(Void... obj) {
         DownloadMethod(s);
         return null;
     }

     @Override
     protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
         progressDialog.dismiss();
     }
 }
```

and call it like `new DownloadFilesTask(s).execute();`

or with generic parameter

```
private class DownloadFilesTask extends AsyncTask<TypeOf_S, Void, Void> {

     @Override
     protected Void doInBackground(TypeOf_S... obj) {
         DownloadMethod(obj[0]);
         return null;
     }

     @Override
     protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
         progressDialog.dismiss();
     }
 }
```

and call it like `new DownloadFilesTask().execute(s);`

Comment: can i use asynctask already inside another method ? because i was doing this , but i had a problem

Comment: yes, you can. if you look at the mentioned link, you need to create a class which extends the AsyncTask , put your method in doinbackground and dismiss the dialog in onpostexecuted, let me know, if you have any issue

Comment: lets say i want to pass the value of s inside my execute new DownloadFilesTask().execute(s);  , so in my doinbackground i want to take this value and put it in my method DownloadTask(s); but it seems that i cant, what should cause this problem ?

Comment: either you can create a parameterize constructor in the class of asyncTask and do `new DownloadFilesTask(s).execute()` or you can define the generic type of first parameter as `class DownloadFilesTask extends AsyncTask<TypeOf_S, Void,Void{...}` and in doinbackground do `protected Void doInBackground(TypeOf_S... obj) {  DownloadMethod(obj[0]);}` then do ``new DownloadFilesTask().execute(s)``

Comment: Thanks a lot dude :)

Answer (score 0):

`progressDialog.dismiss();`is throwing an exception so move your code inside `runOnUiThread()` method like this:

```
 runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                       progressDialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });
```

Answer (score 0):

as suggested by Pavneet you can use async task as follows where `AsyncTask<String, void, String>` corresponds to the input type progress value and last is result value you are interested so give data types accordingly.

```
    private class DownloadFilesTask extends AsyncTask<String, void, String> {
     protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
         //here do the actual downloading instead of calling the DownloadMethod(s)
     }

     protected void onPreExecute() {
         //here show the dialog
         progressDialog.show();
     }

     protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
         //here hide the dialog
         progressDialog.dismiss();
     }
 }
```

and where you are calling the download function you just call this

```
progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
progressDialog.setMessage("Downloading...");
new DownloadFilesTask().execute(s);
//here s is assumed to be string type you can give anything
```